# How to install tarball packages on a Debian based distribution?

Tags: debian, software-installation, source

I would like to know how to install .tar.bz and .tar.bz2 packages on Debian. Could anyone help me understand how to achieve that?

Comment: Those are archives. You need to unpack them and see for instructions inside. Usually it's `./configure`, `make`, `make install`, but I'm sure someone will provide better answer to you, with links where you can learn this very basic things before you actually try to build anything

Comment: Depending on what you want to install, you need also to install the build-essential package and -dev packages of the libraries which are used by the software. Take care that you install to the prefix /usr/local/ (which is normally the default), otherwise you may corrupt your system. For a beginner, I suggest you strongly to restrict yourself to the available packages from Debian. The next step would be to search for already packaged software (.deb packages) and install them then by hand `dpkg -i ./path/to/package.deb`. Using .tar.{gz,bz2} packages, is the last and most difficult option.

Comment: @jofel I agree with you, but some programs are not available in a .deb package and you can only install it from the source code (e.g. Firefox).

Comment: Firefox is most definitely available in the repositories and rarely needs to be built from source.

Comment: @KayakJim I remember that I never could install it from Debian repository. But I'm sure that it's available in the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: @ORpsas For Firefox, see http://superuser.com/questions/322376/how-to-install-real-firefox-on-debian . But as  the newest Firefox version (only re-branded to Iceweasel) is available in Debian experiment or via backports (see http://mozilla.debian.net/ for details), I see no reason why you should need to built it yourself. But in general, I agree with you that there is software which you need to build yourself from tarballs.

Comment: @jofel remember that I just used Firefox as an example.

Comment: What's inside the tarball, and the package name

Comment: If you want to install from sources by hand, the most difficult thing is often installing the right dependencies. If README or INSTALL does not list them, you can need to run the ./configure script by hand (for autoconf based build systems). If it fails with "checking for xyz: No", "xyz not found" or similar, install the package libxyz-dev (on Debian based systems) and try again. If the package does not exists, you need either to find the correct package or to install the needed library by hand first. Sometimes you have to select a specific library version.

Comment: [TuxFiles](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/softinstall.html) has a pretty complete explanation. And it explains how to clean up, and then if necessary later, steps to uninstall as well. It (perhaps) fails the Debian specific part of the question, but is Linux specific.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Firstly, according to the [File System Hierarchy Standards](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html), the location of this installed package should be `/opt` if it is a binary install and `/usr/local` if it's a from source install.

### Pure binaries

These are ready to use binaries. Normally they just need to be extracted to be installed. A binary package is going to be easy:

- `sudo tar --directory=/opt -xvf <file>.tar.[bz2|gz]`
- add the directory to your path: `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/[package_name]/bin`

and you are done.

### From sources

A source package is going to be more troublesome (by far) and through they can roughly be processed with the method below, **each package is different**:

- download the package to `/usr/local/src`
- `tar xf <file>.tar.[bz2|gz]`
- `cd <package name>`
- read the `README` file (this almost certainly exists).
- most Open Source projects use autoconf/automake, the instructions should be in the `README`. Probably this step will go: `./configure && make && make install` (run the commands separately for sanity if something goes wrong though).

**If there's any problems in the install then you'll have to ask specific questions.** You might have problems of incorrect versions of libraries or missing dependencies. There's a reason that Debian packages everything up for you. And there is a reason Debian stable runs old packages - finding all the corner cases of installing packages on more than a dozen different architectures and countless different hardware/systems configurations is difficult. When you install something on your own you might run into one of these problems!

Comment: I made the tar command easier!  You don't need to cd /opt.  Instead cd to where the tarball is and use the tar `-C` or `--directory` option.

Answer (score 10):

Unpack the files and then, in the directory that was created, look for a `README` or `INSTALL` file which will tell you what you need to know in order to install a package (e.g. dependencies, configuration options, commands to run etc...).

Usually it boils down to `./configure`, `make` then `make install`.

Comment: Note that the build will most likely fail in configure.  Why?  Because the source you've downloaded probably has build time dependencies you don't have installed.

On Debian/Ubuntu, if the package also is available with apt, you can install these with:
    sudo apt-get build-dep package-name

Answer (score 7):

The standard way of doing this is:

1. `tar zxvf file.tar.gz` or `tar xvjpf file.tar.bz2`
2. run `./configure`  (`./configure --help` usually gives customization options)
3. run `make`
4. run `make install`

There is usually a README or INSTALL file that gives instructions as well.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, when you install tar.gz/tgz/tar/bz2 (remember, these are just compressed package files) you would need to break open the tar file (`tar xvfz`/`tar xvfj`) and then `cd` to the directory and run `./configure`.

On some systems, you either take the defaults (/usr/local/{lib,bin,etc...} for example) as the default install location, or you might like to use /opt/local/{lib,bin,etc}.

So you would do `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` and then `make`, `make install`.

It us up to you where you want to install your packages. Remember that where ever you decide to do it, you might want to add the path to your PATH shell variable so you can easily run those packages. (often `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin`).

Answer (score 2):

Let me illustrate this with an  example, say you wish to install a package `abc`.
The dependencies of the package `abc` may be identified by reading its documentation. You should resolve the dependencies(required libraries etc) prior to installation for a smooth experience.

> Before a `gcc 4.7.2` build the `g++`, `m4`, `gawk`, `gcc-multilib`,
>   `gmp`, `mpfr`, and `mpc` must be built.

Then comes the building from source part for which the first step is always extraction. This can be done by using the `tar` command or by the simple GUI way. Once you have the extracted files in a folder you must browse to that folder using the `cd` command, for example if the contents are in Downloads then:

`$cd Downloads/abc`

Now you need to run `./configure`. Specify the installation directory by using the `--prefix=` option with `configure`.

> > Firstly, according to the File System Hierarchy Standards, the
> >     location of this installed package should be /opt if it is a binary
> >     install and /usr/local if it's a from source install.

so if you are installing to the `/usr/abc` directory you will supply the option `--prefix=/usr/abc` with the `./configure` instruction.

```
$./configure --prefix=/usr/abc
```

`--prefix=` is not the only thing you might want to specify though, you might want to supply other information for a successful compilation like the type of your system with `--build=x86_64-linux-gnu` for 64 bit, and `--build=i386-linux-gnu` for a 32 bit system. It is wise to read the README in the extracted files as it may carry the information about which options to specify with the `./configure` command.

After the `./configure` run the `make` command, and subsequently the `make install`. 
Post installation you should specify the library path, shell/environment variables using the `export` command.

```
export PATH=/usr/abc/bin:$PATH
```